# Corrupt chrome extensions and user retention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a decently popular Chrome extension, and yesterday I accidentally released a corrupted version of it, and didn't catch it for 10 hours. Within those 10 hours, the extension was updated for most users and I lost about half of them over the night based off of my Google Analytics reports (I had about 600 pageviews every 30 minutes, and now I only have 285). When I found out about my mistake I quickly reverted to an older version that works, but now, about 30 hours after an update that fixes the corruption, my pageviews are still the same.

My questions are:

- Have I lost all those users or has it simply not updated for them yet?
- If an extension is corrupt does it still check for updates or do the users have to press `repair`?

Any insight would be fantastic. As you can imagine, losing half your users over night because of 1 line of code is difficult to process.

Comment: Explain in detail how it is corrupted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What could have happened?

Well, this isn't a really clear situation, but, based on your information, there are a few possible scenarios:

1. **Your users have uninstalled your extension** because of this corrupt version. In this case (the worst one), it's pretty **impossible to bring your users back**, unfortunately.
2. **Your "corrupted" version had issues with the update handling**. For example issues with `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` to check the update and add new features, or issues with the Analytics part. This means that:

   1. Your extension worked fine before the update.
   2. It has been updated with a broken update handling function/method.
   3. The new update (rollback to a working version) didn't solve anything, because **your already corrupted extension is now unable to apply updates and/or send page views to analytics**.
3. **Your users disabled your extension** in an attempt to narrow the issues (that's very uncommon, an edge case).
4. **Your users didn't get the new update** yet (which after thirty hours is also pretty uncommon).

### What could you do?

Again, let's split the situation up:

1. In the first case, you cannot really do anything, unfortunately. That was a bad mistake! Learn from it and **always test a thousand times before pushing updates**.
2. Thinking about the second case? You should **test your corrupted version** on your machine, maybe using [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.it/chrome/browser/canary.html) to make things faster. This obviously means that you should have the previous versions stored somewhere; if you haven't got them, then it gets pretty hard, and for the future: **always keep backups of your previous versions**. Installing the old version, then manually updating to the corrupted one, and finally to the last one, can really help you understand what's going on. You should meticulously check the update method and see if there's something wrong.

   **Note**: if you're not listening to [`chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvalilable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable) and manually calling [`chrome.runtime.reload()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload) to update your extension immediately, a Chrome restart may be necessary for it to update.
3. **Just wait**, although that's uncommon for this situation to happen, but this also is the only thing you can do in such cases.
4. Well, same as case #3.

---

> If an extension is corrupt does it still check for updates or do the users have to press repair?

Well, there's no such thing as a "corrupted extension". Chrome will always check for updates (at least if the user didn't disable them in the `chrome://flags`), even if your extension is just a bunch of `SyntaxError`s. Don't worry about this.

### Extreme fix

In case that you're not sure about what to do, a **re-design of your extension** and a **drastical purge from all the to-dos and bad practices** is always a good thing. Just backup your previous version first, and start working on the 2.0 beta! Possibly, updating and improving the extension will bring much more users to it than just solving an existing issue. Personally, I almost always experienced an installation increase performing drastic restyles and re-writing better code from scratch.

---

I wish you to find the problem and bring your users back ASAP.

> As you can imagine, losing half your users over night because of 1 line of code is difficult to process.

Yes, *I do* imagine. As an extension developer I really suffered for similar mistakes when I was learning update handling. So... well, break a leg! Wish you the best.

Comment: Case 2: if an update is stalled by an extension (only possible if there is a listener to `onUpdateAvailable`, otherwise Chrome applies the update immediately), that stops the update at most until a Chrome restart.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I also forgot to mention that this morning when I checked the webstore for an update of my user count, I was expecting the number to go drastically down, but oddly enough, I had gained 150 users...